# Markov's Theorem

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having a hard time understanding Markov's Theorem. Maybe because I'm very tired, because I think this is a very easy question, but I can't wrap my head around it.

For any set of nonnegative data with the mean $x$, the fraction of the data that are greater than or equal to any positive constant $k$ cannot exceed $x/k$. Use this result, called $Markov's Theorem$ in the following problems.

a) If the mean breaking strength of a certain linen threads is 33.5 ounces, at most what fraction of the threads can have a breaking strength of 50.0 ounces or more?

b) If the diameters of the orange trees in an orchard have a mean of 17.2 cm, at most what fraction of the trees can have a diameter of 20.0 cm or more?

Cheers for the help.

Comment: You can post your own answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it's merely A) 33.5/50=.67  for the first, and B) 17.2/20=.86  for the second. Very easy stuff.

Thanks @Nate Eldredge